# Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks in Asp.Net MVC .NetFramework 4.8

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.8, health-check

Has anyone used Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks in ASP.Net MVC application. I am trying to integrate it ASP.Net MVC hosted in .NetFrameWork 4.8. Most samples on the web are about using it in .Net Core. Any pointer on how we can use it would help.

Comment: i found this [article](https://imar.spaanjaars.com/609/implementing-health-checks-in-aspnet-framework-applications) for .net framework. check if this is helpful.